# How to put a hard space in discord.js embed messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to put some data with colons separating them, but want to ensure the colon lines up horizontally on each line. Only way is to padd it with spaces, except multiple adjacent spaces get collapsed into 1 space. How can I force a space? In html it is possible using a html entity `&nbsp;` for non breaking space, but wondering how do do it in discord.js? Using `\u200B` didn't work either.

I have like

```
.addFields(
  { name : 'Stats' , value : 'A : test\r\nBBBB : test2'}
)
```

This will turn into

```
Stats
A : test
BBBB : test2
```

but I want it more like

```
Stats
A    : test
BBBB : test2
```

Comment: Have you figured this out? having the same issue. The \ suggestion below does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use code blocks in your discord message. The text is displayed in monospaced font and can be arranged by using spaces and linefeeds.
Complete info: https://gist.github.com/matthewzring/9f7bbfd102003963f9be7dbcf7d40e51#syntax-highlighting

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Agree with the comment about this answer being unclear. 

Need to add info about how do use code blocks in your answer rather than a link out.  

That said, adding the ```  (3 backticks) before and after my text worded beautifully with string.PadLeft to make a chart.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be an exact solution, it may help some so I will add this. Discord filters some characters from messages that they believe are problematic. Assuming discord.js doesn't filter out additional characters there are some unicode spaces that appear to work. In my case I wanted to add a blank inline field. I was able to add a zero width space.

Example

```js
const msg = JSON.stringify({
  username: "Example",
  content: "Example Content",
  embeds: [
    {
      title: "Title",
      description: "Test",
      color: 16758413,
      fields: [
        {
          name: "Header 1",
          value: "Some Data",
          inline: true,
        },
        {
          name: `​`,
          value: `​`,
          inline: true,
        },
        {
          name: "Header 3",
          value: "Some More Data",
          inline: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

While you cannot see it, there is a zero width space in index 1 of the fields array between the backticks. You might be able to play with other types of unicode spaces to see if you can bypass that filter. On Mac `ctrl+cmd - space` will open the character viewer. You can then search for `space` to see various unicode spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to embrace your string with magic quote (`) like:

```js
addFields([{
  name: "Stats",
  value: "`A    : test\nBBBB : test2`"
}, {
  name: "Stats",
  value: `\`A    : ${"test"}\nBBBB : test2\``
}]);
```

Both are identic, the second one allow you to use string templating.

Answer (score -1):

use "\ " (backslash, then space) and that will force the additional spaces to appear.  Do that for as many spaces as you need, as often as you need them.

Comment: this does not work, maybe it did before, but it does not now